# Templates and inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am trying to set up class hierarchy as follows:

```
template< class TProcess>
class Path
{
protected:
    TProcess &process;
    double Xt;
public:
    Path(TProcess &process, double X0) : process(process), Xt(X0) {}
    virtual ~Path(){}

    virtual double dX(double dt, const std::vector<double> &dW) = 0;
};

template< class TProcess>
class Process
{
protected:
    double X0;
public:
    Process(double X0) : X0(X0) {}
    virtual ~Process(){}

    virtual boost::shared_ptr<Path<TProcess> > NewPath() =0;
};
```

but then I found it impossible to declare subclasses so that it works. I tried:

```
class GeometricBrownianMotion;
class GBMPath: public Path<GeometricBrownianMotion>
{
    double dX(double dt, const std::vector<double> &dW)
    {
        Xt = Xt*exp(process.mu*dt - 0.5*dt + process.sigma*dW);
        return Xt;
    }
};

class GeometricBrownianMotion: public Process<GeometricBrownianMotion>
{
    double mu;
    const std::vector<double> &sigma;
    double sigma2;
public:
    GeometricBrownianMotion(double X0, double mu, const std::vector<double> &sigma): Process(X0), mu(mu), sigma(sigma), sigma2(sigma*sigma)
    {}

    virtual boost::shared_ptr<Path<GeometricBrownianMotion> > NewPath()
    {
        return boost::shared_ptr<Path<GeometricBrownianMotion> >(new GBMPath(*this, X0));
    }

};
```

but I get the following error:

```
process.h:58: error: forward declaration of ‘struct GeometricBrownianMotion’
process.h:63: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct GeometricBrownianMotion’
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just separate your implementation from your class definitions, and the problem will go away nearly automatically.

Nearly, because you might just want to move the definition of `GeometricBrownianMotion` before using it as a template parameter.

EDIT: even not nearly, at least on my compiler, removing all inline methods definitions was just enough to get it to compile.

Comment: Removing inline method definitions from `GeometricBrownianMotion` and `GBMPath`?